# Efficiently store upper triangular NumPy array in memory

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

Is there a way to efficiently store an upper triangular NumPy array in memory? After some tests using `psutil`, I noticed the following two matrices use equal amounts of memory, despite the one being half empty:

```py
import numpy as np

n = 2048

upper_triangular = np.triu(np.ones((n,n)))
not_upper_triangular = np.ones((n,n))
```

Is there a more memory efficient way for NumPy to store such matrices (e.g. only store upper triangular values in memory) without sacrificing much CPU efficiency?

Comment: Not that I know of. There's a [sparse matrix class](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//scipy/reference/sparse.html), but I wouldn't call upper-triangular matrices sparse. You may want to write a custom class.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [2]: A = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

In [3]: Au = np.triu(A)

In [4]: A
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [5]: Au
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 0,  0, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 15]])
```

`triu` sets the lower triangle values to 0.  Otherwise it's the same size array.

We can get the upper tri indices with:

```
In [7]: np.triu_indices_from(A)
Out[7]: (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]))
```

This is a `nonzero` style tuple of index arrays.  We can use those to select all the upper tri values in a compact 1d array:

```
In [8]: A[np.triu_indices_from(A)]
Out[8]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7, 10, 11, 15])
```

We could recreate the full 2d array with:

```
In [14]: B = np.zeros((4,4),int)
In [20]: B[np.triu_indices(4)] = Out[8]
In [21]: B
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 0,  0, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 15]])
```

At least with `numpy` the memory savings of this compact form is not worth the extra work required to use it.  Still  `scipy.spatial.distance` has distance functions that return a condensed form, and utilities to convert it to `squareform`.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html#scipy.spatial.distance.squareform